# How to extract a substring from a string by a specific pattern

Tags: java

I have a String object like `DUMMY_CONTENT_DUMMY`
The part before or after `_` are actually gibberish 
What's needed is the one between the two underscores. 
Is there a way, in java, to extract that content out ?
Perhaps I have to write a `regex`?

Comment: `String#split("_")`?

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do this in Java and right now your question is very open-ended and doesn't show much in the way of research. SO discourages opinion-based questions or questions that would generate lots of discussion. http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 5):

In this case you do not need regex.

```
String str = "DUMMY_CONTENT_DUMMY";
String content = str.split("_")[1];
```

Comment: Jokes on you, split takes a regex pattern as an argument :) (+1 nevertheless)

Answer (score 1):

```
String x = "AA_BB_CC";    
String[]  arr = x.split("_");  
String middle = arr[1];
```

Here ***middle*** contains your middle part which is "BB" in thsi case.

Answer (score 0):

If you did it with a regex, you could use those underscores preceded or followed by characters as clues for lookahead and lookbehind techniques.  Using Friedl's book on Regular Expressions, I hacked up this code as an example.

```
    /* example method from reference
    *   REF:  Friedel, J. Mastering Regular Expressions.  Ch8: Java.  circa. p.371.
    */

      public static void simpleRegexTest(){

    String myText = "DUMMY_CONTENT_DUMMY";
    String myRegex = "(?<=.*_)(.*)(?=_.*)"; 

    // compile the regex into a pattern that can be used repeatedly
    java.util.regex.Pattern p = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(myRegex);
    // prepare the pattern to be applied to a given string
    java.util.regex.Matcher m = p.matcher(myText);
    // apply the pattern to the current region and see if the a match is found
    // if will return the first match only
    // while will return matches until there are no more

    while (m.find()){
        // use the match result
        // get the span of text matched with group()
        // in this particular instance, we are interested in group 1
        String matchedText = m.group(1);
        // get the index of the start of the span with start()
        int matchedFrom = m.start();
        // get the index of the end of the span with end()
        int matchedTo = m.end();

        System.out.println("matched [" + matchedText + "] " +
                " from " + matchedFrom +
                " to " + matchedTo + " .");

    }
```

When I ran it, the results returned were:
matched [CONTENT]  from 6 to 13 .

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you do it using RegEx.

```
String middlePart = yourString.replaceAll("[^_]*_([^_]*)_[^_]*", "$1");
```